# React Google Login not returning Refresh Token

Tags: php, reactjs, google-api, google-oauth

First, I am using the package `react-oauth/google` which can be found [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google).

It's a very basic setup:

```
import {useGoogleLogin} from "@react-oauth/google";
```

And

```
const googleSignIn = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess,
    isSignedIn: true,
    accessType: "offline", // Should this not insinuate refresh token?
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
    responseType: "code",
    prompt: "consent",
});

const onSuccess = (res) => {
    console.log (res);
    api.post(apiUrl() + "api/v2/gmb/success/", 
      {access_token: res.access_token})
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
       // ...  Do something
    });

};
```

The response from console is:

```
{
   access_token: 'ya29.xxxx', 
   token_type: 'Bearer', 
   expires_in: 3599, 
   scope: 'email profile openid https://www.googleapis.com/ ... ', 
   authuser: '0',
   promp: 'consent',
}
```

I then pass to my `api/v2/gmb/success/` where I store the access token, and store information gethered with said token:

```
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?fields=name,email,id,picture,verified_email';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token));
    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

I am successful in using the access token returned in getting/setting information in Google My Business using my own API (built in PHP) `api/v2/gmb/success/`...  But the access token expires after one hour.  Should there not be a refresh token supplied from google during the initial interaction?  According to [This Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/refresh-token#php) You need a refresh token to GET a refresh token.  I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming in on this in the future ..  To get your Refresh token, once Auth has happened, you can use the following.  You need to add `flow: "auth-code"` to the initial login in the JS ..

```
const googleSignIn = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess,
    onFailure,
    isSignedIn: true,
    accessType: "offline",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
    responseType: "code",
    prompt: "consent",
    flow: 'auth-code'
});
```

This will return the following:

```
authuser: "0"
code: "4/0AWgavdcxxxxxxxx"
prompt: "consent"
scope: "email profile https://www. ...
```

You then pass that `code` to your backend:

```
const onSuccess = (res) => {
        console.log (res);
        api.post(apiUrl() + "api/v2/gmb/success/", 
            {code: res.code})
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            // .. Do Stuff
        });
    };
```

Once there you can just use a simple CURL statement.  This is written in PHP, but can be written in any back end language.

```
$code = $_POST['code']
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';

$curlPost = 'client_id=' . $client_id . '&redirect_uri=postmessage&client_secret=' . $client_secret . '&code=' . $code . '&grant_type=authorization_code';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($http_code != 200)
    throw new Exception('Error : Failed to receive access token -->' . print_r($data, true));

print_r($data);
```

Your response should come back:

```
Array
(
  [access_token] => ya29.a0AX9G****
  [expires_in] => 3599
  [refresh_token] => 1//01BzUAp_l****
  [scope] => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/ ....
  [token_type] => Bearer
  [id_token] => eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtp...
)
```

Then you are free to grab access tokens with your refresh token as often as you'd like with the user only needing to consent a single time.